# Creation of a personnalised page404controller symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

Since a few days I have been looking for a way to create a personnalised page404controller with symfony 2.8 however I didn't find any help about this. The only bit of information I've been able to get is on KnpUniversity :
[KnpUniversity example](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/render-controller)

However since the example is not complete, I dont understand at all what to do.
I already have my personnalised error404.html.twig.
If u have any basic template to this controller, and some explanation about it, I would be very grateful.
For any complementary  informations don't hesitate.
As I'm a beginner I dont understand a lot about error controller creation.

Yes, I have already read [this symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html) but it does not help me.

Here is an example of an URL that I have to check:
[my.website.com/en/hotel/england/london/palacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426964/creation-of-a-personnalised-page404controller-symfony-2-8)

The en/{hotel|villa}/england/london/palacio is correct as an url but the page doest exist so what i do is show a button where i can redirect to :
[my.website.com/en/hotel/england/london/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426964/creation-of-a-personnalised-page404controller-symfony-2-8) 
but in the case where the is URl is not corresponding with fr or en and hotel or villa then just show a button to go to the homepage. 
The composition of my  URl is made from the database. So I want to check each part to the database table corresponding to the 3 last element of my url. the two first are easier as shown is the example under this.

## Error404Controller

```
<?php

namespace FrontendBundle\Controller;



class Error404Controller extends Controller
 {
/*
 * @Route(
 *        "/{_locale}/{_type}/{$countryName}/{$cityName}/{$etablishementName}",
 *        requirements={
 *        "_locale": "en|fr",
 *        "_type": "hotels|villas|restaurants"
 *        }
 *      )
 */
public function showExceptionAction($countryName,$cityName,$etablishementName)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $events = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Error404')
                 ->getUpcomingEvents();
    //$urlreçu = $request->getUri();
    //$urlredirect =0;
    /*
     * 1)Pays
     * 2)Ville
     * 3)Etablissment
     * Si le Pays existe vérifier la Ville sinon retourner un bouton de redirection sur la home
     * Si la Ville existe vérifier le l'établissement sinon retourner boutons de redirection sur la home et la recherche le pays
     * Si l'établissement existe retourner les bouton home et recherche avec pays,ville,etablisee sinon retourner bouton home/recherche avec 1,2
     *
     * */
    $country = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FrontendBundle::Error404)->findCountryCityByName($countryName);
    $city = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FrontendBundle::Error404)->findCountryCityByName($cityName);
    $etablishement = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FrontendBundle::Error404)->findEtablishementBySlug($etablishementName);

    return $this->render('app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig', array(
        'redirection' => $events,
        ));
   }
  }
```

## Error404 Repository

```
<?php

namespace FrontendBundle\Entity\Repository;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use SG\FrameworkBundle\Model\CrudEntityInterface;


class Error404Repository extends EntityRepository
{
/*
 * Recherche dans sg_content_translation
 */
public function findCountryCityBySlug($slug)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
               ->select('world.published_slug')
               ->from('super_table','world')
               ->where('world.published_slug= ?1')
               ->setParameter(1,$slug);


    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}

public function findEtablishementBySlug($slug){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
               ->select('world.published_slug')
               ->from('my_table','world')
               ->where('world.published_slug= ?1')
               ->setParameter(1,$slug);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
 }
 }
```

Here is **my config.yml**, if I understood well the overriding

```
twig:
   exception_controller: FrontendBundle:Error404:showExceptionAction
```

And this is within **my service.yml**

```
services:
   # twig.controller.exception:
   # class: %twig.controller.exception.class%
   # arguments: ["@twig", "%kernel.debug%", "@doctrine"]
     app.exception_controller:
      class: FrontendBundle\Controller\Error404Controller
      arguments: ['@twig','%kernel.debug%']
```

**I'm unable to replace the Default Exception controller**, or I'm wrong somewhere. Could someone give me an idea about this ? 
I get a :
** Controller "FrontendBundle:Error404:showExceptionAction" for URI "/en/villas/france/bernadette" is not callable. ** and the solution I find on Internet is not axed for ExceptionController.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a 404 in your action ?

Comment: You must also set the 404 response code: Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND

Comment: I write it here again : Symfony is a real decent framework. DO NOT USE a 404 Controller, USE the controller which is called by the route : "/en/villas/france/bernadette" and deal with the response in that controller. This is a regular use case of a MVC framework, nothing exceptional. If the villa, exists : display, if not redirect, if redirection does not exist, 404. Ne pas lever une 404 si on affiche du contenu, rediriger directement vers la route adéquate. Le controller porte la logique : il fait les vérifications et rend une page en fonction, c'est son rôle pas besoin d'un controller 404.

Comment: Le soucis c'est que je souhaite faire uniquement cela sur mes pages 404, car cela ne doit arriver que dans le cas où je suis sur une page 404. C'est pour cela que je force autant >< . Le suivis c'est : Erreur 404 =>404Controller => comparaison dans la BDD => en fonction de afficher les deux bouton sur ma 404.

Comment: If you still want an answer, enable your email address in your profile and I'll email you directly. Sincerely

Comment: Found an answer will post it later but thank you Sylvain :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your request :
In any controller :

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('error message');
```

Is enough to trigger the rendering of a 404.

Edit : Based on your comment :
If a 404 is triggered that means that the page requested doesn't exist.
You can also trigger a 404 in a controller as explained before.

But if you want to display a specific 404 depending on the requested url you should use an Event Listener : 
[Symfony event listener documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types) but this a bit more serious than a basic 404 and a bit far-fetched for just a 404.

EDIT 2 BASED on added info :
I don't think you should use a 404 nor overriding. This is a basic symfony feature

In your regular controller :

```
if (database_check) {
     return $this->render(....);
}

if (otherUrlExists()) {
    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('etablissement_in_city', array('lang' => $lang ...)));
} else {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
}
```

Comment: I'll try, what you said. What i want to do is to get the URL that was written when the page 404 appear, then compare some of the information that was send throught it with my database and then if the information is correct send it to a button to redirect or display another button in case that the url doesn't contain enough right part.

Comment: Alter my answer according to your comment

Comment: Can you provide an example of a URL?

Comment: I added more informations within the main text. I need to do this because my website have a lot of page that come and go as I've got some Establishment that switch from published to offline and so, due to this I also have 404 error. That is why I need this. Q : Do I need to extend my Error404 controller with Exceptioncontroller ?

Comment: I don't see how I do this on a regular controller when it should be passing trough the ExceptionController. I'm sorry, i'm trying to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: You have a HTTP request, interpreted by a router. It is route to a controller, by calling a specific action : IN THIS action, in your regular controller you check if your records exists or are available in the DB right ? then depending on the answer you redirect the user or render required page

Comment: Well I will try to see what u mean, however for now I wont close the subject until I'm finished and have posted a solution. Thank you for your patience. PS : Something like this then : https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Comment: I updated my article, for now I'm unable to use my controller. Even if I did everything that was written on the symfony documentation.